# Sens précis de « l' évènement le plus … depuis »

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps, superlatifs, adjectifs

Quelle est la signification exacte de cette tournure:

> L’événement le plus  `adjectif`  depuis `date`

Est-ce que cela veut dire :

1. Qu'un nouveau maximum a été atteint ce jour, le dernier maximum atteint s'étant produit à la date citée ?
2. Ou que le nouvel événement est deuxième derrière le maximum global à la date précisée ?
3. Ou autre chose ?

Exemple malheureusement aujourd'hui :
http://www.lexpress.fr/actualite/societe/fait-divers/choc-frontal-en-gironde-l-accident-le-plus-dramatique-depuis-1982_1728764.html

Answer (score 1):

Cela signifie qu'entre la date donnée (implicitement exclue) et le moment présent cet évènement est le plus notable. À *strictement* parler, cette phrase n'indique pas s'il y a eu d'autres évènements plus (ou moins) notables à cette date ou avant.

Cependant on imagine facilement que cette date a été donnée parce qu'elle correspond au plus proche évènement qui était plus notable que celui qui vient de se produire aujourd'hui. Il n'est en aucun cas nécessaire que l'évènement d'aujourd'hui ou celui qui s'est supposément produit à cette date soit des « maximums globaux ». La phrase introduit certes un maximum mais dans la portée limitée clairement définie par « depuis ».

Cette tournure est généralement utilisée en réponse à l'hypothétique question « Quelle était la dernière fois où l'on a assisté à un événement d'une ampleur au moins similaire ? ».

Comment: "cet évènement" dans votre première phrase est ambigu pour moi.

Comment: Celui qui est défini par la tournure présentée.

Answer (score 0):

Il faut comprendre ta deuxième proposition :

> Le nouvel événement est deuxième derrière le maximum global à la date précisée

Sinon on dirait simplement "L'évenement le plus *adjectif* jamais observé" par exemple.

Answer (score 0):

**Les 1 et 2 sont valides, ainsi que d'autres.**

- dans les cas 1 et 2, il y a eu un événement similaire à une date passée
- les deux événements (à la date passée, et à ce jour), sont les deux les plus importants, mais sans ordre certain: tout ce qui s'est passé entre les deux est (beaucoup) moins important.

**Il y a aussi le cas fréquent, où on ne dispose pas d'information antérieure à la date fournie.**

Cela arrive très souvent en matière météorologique: l'été le plus chaud depuis, les plus grandes chutes de neige, ... Pour éviter les ambiguité, on précise souvent que la date passée est le début des mesures connues.

A noter que ce genre d'annonces journalistiques est souvent erronnée ou partielle, et manque de préciser les circonstances exactes (dans quel pays, dans quelles conditions, ...)

Comment: La phrase n'indique rien de ce qui s'est passé avant la date donné. Il n'y a pas besoin de connaitre ce qu'il s'est passé avant pour pouvoir formuler une telle affirmation, seulement ce qui s'est passé pendant la période.